# Could not load type 'System.ServiceProviderExtensions' from assembly 'OpenTelemetry, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, prometheus, open-telemetry

**Package References**

```
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Jaeger" Version="1.4.0-beta.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus" Version="1.2.0-rc5"/>
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting" Version="1.0.0-rc9.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0-rc9.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http" Version="1.0.0-rc9.8" />
```

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryMetrics(b =>
{
    b.AddPrometheusExporter();
    b.AddMeter(TelemetryConstants.MyAppSource);
    b.SetResourceBuilder(resource);
    b.AddHttpClientInstrumentation();
    b.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
});
```

When I run the application it's giving the following error

`System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.ServiceProviderExtensions' from assembly 'OpenTelemetry, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7bd6737fe5b67e3c'.'`

at `app.UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint();`

Comment: Could you solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error has gone after adding `opentelemetry.exporter.prometheus.aspnetcore` package.

Answer (score 5):

I saw this issue when I had both `OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus` and `OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus.AspNetCore` packages referenced. Removing the `OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus` package reference solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch the version of OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus back to 1.4.0-alpha.2
At least it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

use OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus --version 1.2.0-beta1